# Defining a C macro and setting a memory address into structure member written in c and c++

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, dll, dll-injection

I'm having a problem with the address of hook_t->addr within this macro below:

Macro:

```
#define HOOK1(library, funcname, hkaddr ) {L###library, #funcname, (void *)&hkaddr, \
                                           &New_##funcname, (void **) &Old_##funcname}
```

Structure: ( With 11 elements )

```
typedef struct _hook_t {
    const wchar_t *library;
    const char *funcname;

    // instead of a library/funcname combination, an address can be given
    // as well (this address has more priority than library/funcname)
    void *addr;

    // pointer to the new function
    void *new_func;

    // "function" which jumps over the trampoline and executes the original
    // function call
    void **old_func;

    // allow hook recursion on this hook?
    // (see comments @ hook_create_pre_trampoline)
    int allow_hook_recursion;

    // this hook has been performed
    int is_hooked;

    unsigned char tramp[128];
    unsigned char pre_tramp[150];
    unsigned char store_exc[128];
    unsigned char hook_data[32];
} hook_t;
```

Data Type:

```
hook_t
```

Array of hook_t's:

```
static hook_t g_hooks[] = {

    HOOK1( 0, Present, VTable[ PR ] )

};
```

Now, I create a pD3D device in two other functions and load the address of Present into the VTable[ PR ] position. The VTable[ PR ] position has global scope to the current file. Using: ( static DWORD VTable[4] = {0}; ).

When I use printf() I can get this address 6D93A064 for VTable[ PR ].

Now VTable[ PR ] is in a global at this point.

So, when I call HOOK1( 0, Present, VTable[ PR ] ) inside the g_hooks[] array. It should have 6D93A064 in VTable[ PR ].

So when it hits the macro:

```
#define HOOK1(library, funcname, hkaddr ) {L###library, #funcname, (void *)&hkaddr, \
                                           &New_##funcname, (void **) &Old_##funcname}
```

hkaddr should be 6D93A064 which should be loaded into the structure position addr:

```
typedef struct _hook_t {
    const wchar_t *library;
    const char *funcname;
    void *addr;
```

Because the array I am using is of type hook_t.

But when I got to printf() the hook_t->addr (address)... Its 13D21814.

It should be 6D93A064.

Why is it the wrong address 13D21814 ??? I don't get it. I've been bashing my head on the keyboard now for about 6 hours trying to figure this out with visual studio and ollydbg.

I don't understand.

Can someone please straighten this issue out for me?

Thanks.

Comment: You should boil this down to a short, complete, compilable example that shows the problem.  Starting with your description at "I create a pD3D device..." I get very lost about what your code is really doing. For example, I don't know what this means: "Now VTable[ PR ] is in a global at this point."

Comment: PR is a enum which is zero

Comment: So, `hook_t->addr = &VTable[PR]`, right?

Comment: Yes its suppose to be like that, but hook_t->addr always has the wrong address. VTable[ PR ] always has the right address. I don't get it.

Comment: Its like the macro and the global variable isn't accepting my address from VTable[ PR ]

Comment: I'm still not sure what your code that you're describing in English prose is really doing (why don't you post it?).  It sounds like you might possibly be using `&VTable[PR]` in one place and `VTable[PR]` (which contains the address of `Present`?) in another place.  But without seeing the code, this is just a guess. Even just the `printf()`'s you mention might be enough.

Comment: The problem was from a pointer which was being changed into a void pointer. I needed to take that pointer and put it into a new pointer to get the same pointer value as the first pointer I originally started with. So, I figured it out. Say that 10 times fast lol...

Answer (score 0):

VTable[ PR ] contains a pointer to the Present() function, in you're macro you're using:

```
(void *)&hkaddr
```

you're trying to hook the address of the pointer, when you should be hooking the address which it points to.

essentially you're hooking  `&VTable[PR]` instead of `VTable[PR]`, just remove the "&" address of operator